# C++ how to insert array into hash set?

Tags: c++, arrays, hashset

I need to insert a 1D array into the hashset.

But I got error while compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <hash_set.h>
using namespace std;
int hash_comp(const int* state1,const int* state2) {
    int result = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
    {
        if (state1[i] != state2[i]) {
            result = -1;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
struct eqArray
{
    bool operator()(const int* a1,const int* a2) const
  {
    return hash_comp(a1,a2) == 0;
  }
};
hash_set<int*,hash<int*>,eqArray> closelist;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   const int sn[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,7,15};
   closelist.insert(sn);
   return 0;
}
```

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/hashtable.h: In member function 'size_t __gnu_cxx::hashtable<_Val, _Key, _HashFcn, _ExtractKey, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::_M_bkt_num_key(const _Key&, size_t) const [with _Val = int*, _Key = int*, _HashFcn = __gnu_cxx::hash<int*>, _ExtractKey = std::_Identity<int*>, _EqualKey = std::equal_to<int*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<int*>]':
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/hashtable.h:599:   instantiated from 'size_t __gnu_cxx::hashtable<_Val, _Key, _HashFcn, _ExtractKey, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::_M_bkt_num(const _Val&, size_t) const [with _Val = int*, _Key = int*, _HashFcn = __gnu_cxx::hash<int*>, _ExtractKey = std::_Identity<int*>, _EqualKey = std::equal_to<int*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<int*>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/hashtable.h:1006:   instantiated from 'void __gnu_cxx::hashtable<_Val, _Key, _HashFcn, _ExtractKey, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::resize(size_t) [with _Val = int*, _Key = int*, _HashFcn = __gnu_cxx::hash<int*>, _ExtractKey = std::_Identity<int*>, _EqualKey = std::equal_to<int*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<int*>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/hashtable.h:437:   instantiated from 'std::pair<__gnu_cxx::_Hashtable_iterator<_Val, _Key, _HashFcn, _ExtractKey, _EqualKey, _Alloc>, bool> __gnu_cxx::hashtable<_Val, _Key, _HashFcn, _ExtractKey, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Val = int*, _Key = int*, _HashFcn = __gnu_cxx::hash<int*>, _ExtractKey = std::_Identity<int*>, _EqualKey = std::equal_to<int*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<int*>]'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/hash_set:197:   instantiated from 'std::pair<typename __gnu_cxx::hashtable<_Value, _Value, _HashFcn, std::_Identity<_Tp>, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::const_iterator, bool> __gnu_cxx::hash_set<_Value, _HashFcn, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::insert(const typename __gnu_cxx::hashtable<_Value, _Value, _HashFcn, std::_Identity<_Tp>, _EqualKey, _Alloc>::value_type&) [with _Value = int*, _HashFcn = __gnu_cxx::hash<int*>, _EqualKey = std::equal_to<int*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<int*>]'
src/ods2.cpp:677:   instantiated from here
```

Comment: By the way, the `.h` headers and all the pointers and the `return 0;` inside `main` suggest that you are learning C++ from a very poor source. Do yourself a favor and buy [a decent book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use a `std::array<int, 16>` instead of `int*`, all your problems will go away. If you have no C++11 compiler, you can use `boost::array` instead. Also, replace `hash_set` with `unordered_set`.

It appears there is no specialization of `std::hash` for `std::array`s, so I wrote my own:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <array>

namespace std
{
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    struct hash<array<T, N> >
    {
        typedef array<T, N> argument_type;
        typedef size_t result_type;

        result_type operator()(const argument_type& a) const
        {
            hash<T> hasher;
            result_type h = 0;
            for (result_type i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                h = h * 31 + hasher(a[i]);
            }
            return h;
        }
    };
}

std::unordered_set<std::array<int, 16> > closelist;

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 16> sn = {1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,7,15};
    closelist.insert(sn);
}
```

Comment: thank you, so what library should I include instead of hash_set.h? and how can I declare these? like {unordered_set<std::array<int,16>,hash<std::array<int,16>>,??which function?> closelist;}

Comment: You could use `#include <tr1/unordered_set>`, `#include <tr1/array>`, and `std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<int, 16> >`.

Comment: I still got error: `
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/hashtable_policy.h:784: error: using invalid field 'std::tr1::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::tr1::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_M_h1'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/src/ods2.o] Error 1`

Comment: `src/ods2.cpp:69: error: specialization of 'template<class T> struct std::tr1::hash' in different namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/functional_hash.h:48: error:   from definition of 'template<class T> struct std::tr1::hash'` src/ods2.cpp:69: error: specialization of 'template<class T> struct std::tr1::hash' in different namespace
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/functional_hash.h:48: error:   from definition of 'template<class T> struct std::tr1::hash'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/src/ods2.o] Error 1

Comment: Wow, your compiler must be quite old :) Either update, or nest the specialization of `hash` inside the `tr1` namespace, that is: `namespace std { namespace tr1 { template ... } }`.

Comment: I'm using the newest MPIC++ for compiling. So I need to do in the second way?

Comment: Wow!..Thank you very much! it is working now. So I need to put  std::array<int, 16> instead of int[16]? I wonder what is the difference?

Comment: `std::array<T, N>` is a zero-overhead wrapper around a `T[N]` that gets rid of all the ridiculous special rules and limitations of C arrays.

Comment: Thank you again! I'm coding this in C, but I didn't find any hashset library in C, so I changed my code into c++. I wonder do you know any hashset in C? and...Can you explain the hash<>function a little bit? so next time when I need a hash<> for 2D array I know how to write it?

Comment: The hash function for arrays simply calls the hash functions for its elements and multiplies them by a prime factor before adding them to an accumulator. This is basically `java.lang.String.hashCode()` if you will ;) You don't need to write a different function for 2D arrays. The code is generic enough for arrays of *any* element type that supports hashing, so it automatically works for multidimensional arrays such as `std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 20>` without any additional effort.

Comment: Where does the magic `31` in your hash calculation come from?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I stole it from `java.lang.String.hashCode`. It seems to be a popular number, because it is prime, and `31 * x` can be implemented quite efficiently as `(x << 5) - x`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t post the actual error message, only the trace. That said, it’s probably because your set uses non-`const` `int*` while your data is `const`.

That said, I’d suggest using `unordered_set` instead of `hash_set`(either from `std::tr1` if your compiler supports that, or from `std` if your compiler supports C++11 or from Boost), and heed Fred’s advice of using an `{std,boost}::array` instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: I got this error message: 
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/hashtable_policy.h:784: error: using invalid field 'std::tr1::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::tr1::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_M_h1'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/src/ods2.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there exists a specialized `hash<int*>`. I added this:

```
namespace __gnu_cxx{ //I'm not sure what compiler version you used,
                     //mine wanted this
    template<>
    struct hash<const int*>{
        size_t operator()(const int*a) const{
            size_t r = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
                r = (r<<1) ^ a[i]; //not sure if it makes sense as a hash.
            return r;
        }
    };
}
```

I also put in some `const`s and it compiles.