# Are there no specializations of std::hash for standard containers?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, hash-function, unordered-set

I [just](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026890/c-how-to-insert-array-into-hash-set/8026914#8026914) found myself a little bit surprised being unable to simply use a

```
std::unordered_set<std::array<int, 16> > test;
```

because there does not seem to be a `std::hash` specialization for `std::array`s. Why is that? Or did I simply not find it? If there is indeed none, can the following implementation attempt be simplified?

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    struct hash<array<T, N> >
    {
        typedef array<T, N> argument_type;
        typedef size_t result_type;

        result_type operator()(const argument_type& a) const
        {
            hash<T> hasher;
            result_type h = 0;
            for (result_type i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                h = h * 31 + hasher(a[i]);
            }
            return h;
        }
    };
}
```

I really feel this should somehow be part of the standard library.

Comment: There really isn't one, only `std::string` and friends have that privilege. Would I be really unpopular if I said that it's because C++'s effort to drag itself towards the current state of the art in terms of standard data structures has not yet done the whole job? Actually, there aren't any required `hash` specializations for templates (and which would in turn require their template arguments to be hashable). The only required specializations are for built-in type and four concrete string classes. So I suspect that a line was drawn there.

Comment: @Steve: Which 4 concrete string classes?

Comment: `string`, `u16string`, `u32string`, `wstring` (21.6 in C++11). I'd say that `pair` and `tuple` should be the next-highest-priority targets, followed by standard containers, followed by a default hash for any aggregate type composed of hashable members.

Comment: Obviously the `string` hasher requires an internal function for hashing a block of memory.  I wonder why they did not require implementations to expose it directly?

Comment: @Nemo: I don't think it's necessarily that simple, the collation locale facet has a `hash` function of its own, presumably so that you can collapse different characters together in a locale-dependent manner to keep `hash` consistent with comparisons. So it is exposed, but I don't know whether or not the specializations of `std::hash` for string types are supposed to use it, I'm not properly familiar with this stuff.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I would look up the code of `boost::hash_combine`, were I to implement hashing on collection.

Comment: @nemo Nobody wrote it up as a paper to the committee. Things only get into the standard if somebody cares enough to make it happen.

Comment: `boost::hash_combine` uses `seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);` if anyone is curious. That looks a bit more robust.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this code in theory results in undefined behavior (at least in C++11), because the declaration does not depend on a user-defined type. From §17.6.4.2.1.1:

"A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-deﬁned type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure why the standard library hasn't included this, but Boost has hashing for all sorts of things made up from hashable types. The key function for this is `hash_combine`, which you are welcome to copy from `boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp`.

Using `hash_combine`, Boost derives a `range_hash` (just combining the hashes of a each element of a range), as well as pair and tuple hashers. The `range_hash` in turn can be used to hash any iterable container.

Comment: Yeah, `range_hash` sounds like it should be in the standard.

Answer (score 12):

Not an answer, but some useful information.  The Feb draft of the C++11 standard specifies that `std::hash` is specialized for these types:

- `error_code` § 19.5.5
- `bitset<N>` § 20.5.3
- `unique_ptr<T, D>` § 20.7.2.36
- `shared_ptr<T, D>` § 20.7.2.36
- `type_index` § 20.13.4
- `string` § 21.6
- `u16string` § 21.6
- `u32string` § 21.6
- `wstring` § 21.6
- `vector<bool, Allocator>` § 23.3.8
- `thread::id` § 30.3.1.1

And all these types: § 20.8.12

```
template <> struct hash<bool>;
template <> struct hash<char>;
template <> struct hash<signed char>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned char>;
template <> struct hash<char16_t>;
template <> struct hash<char32_t>;
template <> struct hash<wchar_t>;
template <> struct hash<short>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned short>;
template <> struct hash<int>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned int>;
template <> struct hash<long>;
template <> struct hash<long long>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned long>;
template <> struct hash<unsigned long long>;
template <> struct hash<float>;
template <> struct hash<double>;
template <> struct hash<long double>;
template<class T> struct hash<T*>;
```