# How to insert a array into unordered set?

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, unordered-set

I want to create a tuple/array like `(0,1,2), (3,4,5)`. I want to store it into an `unordered_set`. But `unordered_set` didn't offer such a hash function. Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

I have read thes answer:
[C++ how to insert array into hash set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026890/c-how-to-insert-array-into-hash-set) 
but I don't want to add any extra code like hash function.

Comment: There is no alternative but to add a hash function. Because std libraries don't provide the hash function for tuple and arrays. You can create your own templatized hash class which can be reused.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I want to store [array] into an unordered_set
> 2. unordered_set didn't offer such a hash function
> 3. I don't want to add any extra code like hash function.

Tough luck. A hash function is mandatory. Since it's not provided by the standard library, it must be provided by you. The answer in the question you linked shows how to write a hash function for `std::array`.