# Using an unordered_map with arrays as keys

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

I don't understand why I can't have an `unordered_map` with an `array<int,3>` as the key type:

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   array<int,3> key = {0,1,2};

   unordered_map< array<int,3> , int >  test;
   test[key]  = 2;

   return 0;
}
```

I get a long error, the most pertinent part being

```
main.cpp:11:9: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are std::unordered_map<std::array<int, 3ul>, int>’ and ‘std::array<int, 3ul>’)
 test[key]  = 2;
     ^
```

Are arrays not eligible to be keys because they miss some requirements?

Comment: I get an error saying there is no hash function for the array.  I guess this is expected and you should implement one.  _"error: no match for call to '(const std::hash<std::array<int, 3ull> >) (const std::array<int, 3ull>&)'"_  GCC 5.1.0

Comment: Thanks to all people who pointed the lack of a hash function for arrays. I  naively thought it's a pretty common thing, for example to store a sparse matrix (not what I'm doing here).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Why?**

As mentioned in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

> Internally, the elements in the unordered_map are not sorted in any
>   particular order with respect to either their key or mapped values,
>   but organized into buckets depending on their hash values to allow for
>   fast access to individual elements directly by their key values (with
>   a constant average time complexity on average).

Now as per your question we need to `hash` an array which has not been implemented internally in standard c++.

**How to get over with it?**

So if you want to map an `array` to a value you must implement your own std::hash http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash for which you might get some help from [C++ how to insert array into hash set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026890/c-how-to-insert-array-into-hash-set).

**Some work around**

If you are free to use `boost` then it can provide you with hashing of arrays and many other types. It basically uses `hash_combine` method for which you can have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp.

Answer (score 14):

You have to implement a hash. Hash tables depending on hashing the key, to find a bucket to put them in. C++ doesn't magically know how to hash every type, and in this particular case it doesn't know how to hash an array of 3 integers by default. You can implement a simple hash struct like this:

```
struct ArrayHasher {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::array<int, 3>& a) const {
        std::size_t h = 0;

        for (auto e : a) {
            h ^= std::hash<int>{}(e)  + 0x9e3779b9 + (h << 6) + (h >> 2); 
        }
        return h;
    }   
};
```

And then use it:

```
unordered_map< array<int,3> , int, ArrayHasher >  test;
```

Edit: I changed the function for combining hashes from a naive xor, to the function used by boost for this purpose: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/hash_combine_id241013.html. This should be robust enough to actually use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, I don't know much about hashes function and what makes a good hash function, so I guess I'll just move to ordered maps and suffer an additional log complexity time!

Comment: @Adrien Well the biggest hit with ordered maps is probably not the logN time, but the really bad cache coherency. Also, combining hashes well can be done with a simple formula; see the edit to my answer. You should be able to use the code above as is in your project.

Comment: The answer no longer compiles.  It needs ` std::size_t operator()(const std::array<int, 3>& a) const {` instead.

Answer (score 8):

The relevant error is

`error: no match for call to '(const std::hash<std::array<int, 3ul> >) (const std::array<int, 3ul>&)'`

The `unordered_map` needs a hash of the key, and it looks for an overload of `std::hash` to do that. You can extend the `namespace std` with a suitable hash function.

Answer (score 2):

Compiled with msvc14 gives the following error:

> "The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type."

I guess this is self-explanatory.