# Why does std::set<array<int,N>> work but not std::unordered_set<array<int,N>>?

Tags: c++, hash, stl, unordered-map, unordered-set

Same goes for `std::unordered_map` vs `std::map`. It means that `std::map` can store objects of type `std::array<T,N>` for primitive T's but `std::unordered_map` cannot.

Comment: Did you provide a hash function?

Comment: I didn't for either

Comment: Simple, there is no `std::hash` specialization for `std::array`.

Comment: Once you do, it should work. [See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

Comment: Good question should contain [mcve] also `doesn't work` is not description of a problem. Doesn't compile? What is error message? Crashes? What is a crash log? Give invalid results? What are they?

Answer (score 0):

`std::array<T, N>` is not hashable by default. So, you need to implement your own hashing function for this type. A simple example hash function can be like this (adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42701911/896012)):

```
#include <set>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_set>

const int N = 10;


struct array_hasher
{
   std::size_t operator()(std::array<int, N> const& arr) const 
   {
      std::size_t seed = 0;
      for (const auto& i : arr) 
      {
         seed ^= std::hash<int>{}(i) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
      }
      return seed;
   }
};

int main()
{
   std::set<std::array<int, N>> x = {};
   std::unordered_set<std::array<int, N>, array_hasher> y = {};

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a good tidbit, but it's worth pointing out that `unordered_set` requires that its members have unchanging values.  That is, if the array or its hash changes, all guarantees go out the window.

Comment: Oh so std::set doesn't need a hashing function?

Comment: @abcdefasf `std::set` is ordered. You need comparison instead.

Comment: @TimRoberts Agreed ! In an `unordered_set<>`, each object's value is its key. So, the objects should not be changed.

Comment: @abcdefasf As pointed by @Deduplicator, `std::set` is a tree-like data structure. It means that it always needs a comparison mechanism for its elements (which is already supported by `std::array` itself). On the other hand, `std::unordered_set` is a hash-table-like data structure, so it needs a hashing function for its elements. As far as this hashing function does not exist by default in standard library (for `std::array`), you need to implement it yourself !

Comment: Specializing `std::hash` on a `std::array<int, N>` is UB. Furthermore, that's a really bad hash function.

Comment: More specifically, specializing `std::hash` on a standard library type is Undefined Behavior.  And this hash only produces odd numbers.

Comment: No reason to specialize `std::hash` for `std::array` (technical UB) Just add a lambda